# OpenCV - Are Lens Distortion Coefficients inverted for projectPoints?

Tags: python, opencv, simulation, distortion

Good day guys,

I am trying to simulate and image with lens barrel distortion. I create a virtual chessboard (only the corners) and then project it onto my image plane using OpenCV. The idea is to project these points with known distortion coefficients, and then attempt a lens distortion calibration (with `calibrateCamera`), and see if the same coefficients are obtained.

**My question** is about the `projectPoints` function which takes `distCoeffs` as an input. Are these coefficients the same that must be used to *undistort* an image (output of `calibrateCamera`)? This means the function will have to calculate the inverse of that operation. Or, does it use those coefficients to distort the object points directly? Meaning that the will not correlate at all at the output of e.g. `calibrateCamera`.

I ask, because I noticed my simulation does pincushion distortion when I expect barrel, and vica versa. Which seems that the distortion does the opposite of what I think it does.

The minimal working code that I used to simulate the image (in Python):

```
# The distortion matrix that I vary
distortion = np.array([0.3, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01])

# Generate Grid of Object Points
grid_size, square_size = [20, 20], 0.2
object_points = np.zeros([grid_size[0] * grid_size[1], 3])
mx, my = [(grid_size[0] - 1) * square_size / 2, (grid_size[1] - 1) * square_size / 2]
for i in range(grid_size[0]):
    for j in range(grid_size[1]):
        object_points[i * grid_size[0] + j] = [i * square_size - mx, j * square_size - my, 0]

# Setup the camera information
f, p = [5e-3, 120e-8]
intrinsic = np.array([[f/p, 0, 0], [0, f/p, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
rvec = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
tvec = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 3.0])

# Project the points
image_points, jacobian = cv2.projectPoints(object_points, rvec, tvec, intrinsic, distortion)

# Plot the points (using PyPlot)
plt.scatter(*zip(*image_points[:, 0, :]), marker='.')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.xlim((-4000, 4000))
plt.ylim((-4000, 4000))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

**Additional Explanation:**

My query is about the wrong distortion type being created. If I use a positive distortion matrix, then I would expect barrel distortion, according to [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) website, which states:

> The next figure shows two common types of radial distortion: barrel distortion (typically k_1 > 0) and pincushion distortion (typically k_1 < 0).

To test this I used the following **positive** distortion matrix (as in the code above), and it created pincushion distortion.

```
distortion = np.array([0.3, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01])
```

[image: Expected Barrel Distortion, but got Pincushion]

In this image I clearly created pincushion distortion, and not barrel distortion.

Similarly, if I make my distortion coefficient **negative**, which should result in pincushion distortion, I get the following:

```
distortion = -np.array([0.3, 0.001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.01])
```

[image: Expected Pincushion distortion, got barrel distortion]

Does this mean that the distortion matrix is applied negatively if you use the `projectPoints` function?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess this is just a matter of the pinhole model used by opencv and the one you are used to.  you can think it as the `physical` pinhole where the image is projected inverted. Like (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Pinhole-camera.svg)  But many times, we use a model where the projection is in front and not inverted (https://openmvg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_images/pinholeCamera.png).  These 2 models are quite the same, the difference is only in the signal of the dimensions.

Comment: @Fred, thank you for your comment! I am aware of the difference you talk about, but that would create a inverted `x` and `y` axis, which is not what I'm struggling with. Instead the wrong distortion type is created. I updated my question to make this more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `distCoeffs` in `projectPoints` are of the same type that `calibrateCamera` outputs. I ran a more thorough simulation where I added distortion using `projectPoints`, and then estimated it again using `calibrateCamera`, and it gave me the *same* distortion matrix.

E.g with the following code

```
distortion_given = np.array([[0.2, 0.01,  0.0, 0.0, 0.01]])# Note the negative sign
... = projectPoints(... , distortion_given , ...)
... , distortion_estimated , ... = calibrateCamera (...)
print (distortion_given)
print (distortion_estimated)
```

which created the following projected image with Barrel distortion

[image]

Resulted in:

```
distortion_given = [[-0.2, -0.01,  0.0, 0.0, -0.01]]
distortion_estimated = [[-0.19999985 -0.01000031  0.          0.         -0.00999981]]
```

This means that when [this](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html) website I mentioned in the question should put more emphasis on the word *typically*, as I observed the opposite.

> barrel distortion (typically k_1 > 0) and pincushion distortion (typically k_1 < 0).